# Wordpress - Multilingual translation at once

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anyone have a solution or some translation plugin for this? I need to develop a website that will have texts (soon on the home page) with different languages. Spanish, English, French and Portuguese. Each person will post to the manager in their native language. But when accessing the site in one of these countries, should the site automatically translate each text into the language referring to the country of access? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need two plugins:

1. WPML https://wpml.org/
2. WPML Redirect Based on IP Country https://wpml.org/plugin/wpml-redirect-based-on-ip-country/